# Ping App Animation Android

Tags: android, animation

I am just curious. How do I implement animation in [ping app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ly.secret.ping&hl=en.) when I start/replace one activity/fragment from other. In IOS we can add a mask layer in oval shape and modify the alpha values. How do i implement this in android?

Comment: This is a very general question. You should start looking into Android transitions as Gaskoin suggests. If you run into problems there, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

Create the `shape.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</shape>
```

Set it to your `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp" //or another
    android:layout_height="60dp" //or another
    android:id="@+id/ping"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/shape" />
```

Then create two animations `scale_up.xml` and `scale_down.xml`:

### scale_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:toYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillBefore="true" />
</set>
```

### scale_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.5"
        android:fromYScale="1.5"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillBefore="true" />
</set>
```

And finally `startAnimation()` in code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView ping = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ping);

    final Animation scaleDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_down);
    final Animation scaleUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_up);

    scaleDown.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ping.startAnimation(scaleUp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    scaleUp.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ping.startAnimation(scaleDown);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    ping.startAnimation(scaleUp);
}
```